# DECODE function in ORACLE does not give date 01-01-1900 as output

Tags: oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper, decode

In oracle in our project where DECODE function is the recommended guideline to use them, there are issues when converting the date 01-01-1900.
Consider the below decode

```
CAST(DECODE(COL1,'A',DATECOL,TO_DATE('01011900','DDMMYYYY')) AS DATE) - (The CAST is also a mandatory guideline)

If,
COL1 DATECOL
A    2019-04-05
B    2018-01-01
C    2020-05-01
```

I get the resulting data as

```
COL1 OUTPUT
A    2019-04-05
B    2000-01-01
C    2000-01-01
```

The DECODE function gives me 2000-01-01 instead of 1900-01-01.
I have checked out the NLS parameters and dabbles around by modifying different things in TO_DATE function. Nothing worked out.

Comment: Is this your real code with real values? It should work.

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4f2be0b6f318676cc956bf07be69d8b6

Comment: Works OK, I agree. Though, if DATECOL column's datatype is DATE, why do you CAST it to DATE again? This is enough: `DECODE(COL1, 'A', DATECOL, DATE '1900-01-01')`

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that your DATECOL in the database is actually a string? Because if that is the case, then DECODE always takes the first potential return item to set the datatype. And once you start mixing and matching datatypes, bad things can be happen.

For example

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'YY-MM-DD';

Session altered.

SQL> with t as
  2  ( select 'A' col1, '2010-01-01' datecol from dual union all
  3    select 'B' col1, '2010-01-01' datecol from dual )
  4  select  CAST(DECODE(COL1,'A',DATECOL,TO_DATE('01011900','DDMMYYYY')) AS DATE)
  5  from t;

CAST(DEC
--------
10-01-01
00-01-01
```

That seems to look OK, but if I dig into the value that actually came back after all the jumping through datatypes

```
SQL> with t as
  2  ( select 'A' col1, '2010-01-01' datecol from dual union all
  3    select 'B' col1, '2010-01-01' datecol from dual )
  4  select  to_char(CAST(DECODE(COL1,'A',DATECOL,TO_DATE('01011900','DDMMYYYY')) AS DATE),'dd-mm-yyyy')
  5  from t;

TO_CHAR(CA
----------
01-01-2010
01-01-2000
```

you can see that the lack of a full century specification has "mangled" the result.  In particular, the tools you are using (SQL Developer and others) will have their *own* formatting of results which can mask what might be happening with datatypes.